# MySQL - installation from source failed on ./configure

Tags: snow-leopard, install, mysql

I'm following this How-to on installing MySQL on Snow Leopard but instead of using MySQL 5.1 I'm downloading the source for MySQL 5.5.11

so when I go into the source directory and run:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-extra-charsets=complex \
--enable-thread-safe-client --enable-local-infile --enable-shared \
--with-plugins=innobase
```

I get:

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I imagine you're not in the actual source directory for MySQL when running that command.

Comment: It was because the new source packages require some `cmake` compiler... so i installed that compiler or whatever it is and then did `cmake .` -> `make` -> `sudo make install` what i don't know now is how to get the extra parameters to `cmake . `

Comment: Seems MySQL needs to update their install docs :D.

Comment: This sort of issue requiring several programs is often eased by using a ports system e.g. Macports, fink, homebrew - where someone else has dealt with getting all the correct command lines

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you install MySQL from the DMG image - it works.

BUT - I'm not able to start v5.5.11 after the install, so I'm back on v5.1.56. It should only be a problem when installed on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score -2):

You've downloaded the binary version, not the source.

This is the reason that you're getting the config error.

:)

Comment: This contradicts the statement in the question...